# Vagrant plugin can't find vagrant-berkshelf

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

I'm having a great deal of difficulty with vagrant-berkshelf. Currently I get an error stating it's not found, so I installed the `chef-dk` as a system package as instructed.

`vagrant` still can't find the `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin. I then tried:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf --plugin-version 2.0.1
```

from which I got a failure as many dependcies weren't installed:

```
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:153:in `gather_dependencies': Unable to resolve dependencies: vagrant-berkshelf requires c
elluloid (~> 0.16.0.pre), celluloid-io (~> 0.16.0.pre); berkshelf requires addressable (~> 2.3.4),...
```

I installed these and `gem list` confirms it.

I still get the error. Can somebody explain how paths work in vagrant and where it's looking for what, and why it didn't find the plugin after I installed `chef-dk`. This isn't multiple questions; the path question should solve the others, unless I'm very much mistaken.

And also:

```
$ vagrant plugin list
vagrant-berkshelf (4.0.1)
vagrant-cachier (1.1.0)
vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1)
```

Comment: Worth a read: https://sethvargo.com/the-future-of-vagrant-berkshelf/  The community appears to be shifting over to using test kitchen instead.

Comment: Thanks, however I need a particular cookbook to work and don't have time to switch over

Answer (score 0):

The current version of `vagrant-berkshelf` is `4.0.1`. Trying to install the very old `2.0.1` version is probably just broken due to shifting dependency versions. I would recommend installing the current version instead.

Comment: But `vagrant plugin` shows v4 is installed as stated in the question; however vagrant can't find it.

Comment: What makes you think it can't find the plugin?

Comment: It says it can't find the plugin upon attempted provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states:

```
Unable to resolve dependencies: vagrant-berkshelf requires celluloid (~> 0.16.0.pre), celluloid-io (~> 0.16.0.pre);
```

vagrant-berkshelf is installed but you're missing some of it's dependencies.

These gems can be installed with:

```
gem install celluloid celluloid-io
```